# What is the equivalent of memset in C#?

Tags: c#, memset, equivalent

I need to fill a `byte[]` with a single **non-zero** value. How can I do this in C# without looping through each `byte` in the array?

**Update:** The comments seem to have split this into two questions -

1. Is there a Framework method to fill a byte[] that might be akin to `memset`
2. What is the most efficient way to do it when we are dealing with a very large array?

I totally agree that using a simple loop works just fine, as Eric and others have pointed out. The point of the question was to see if I could learn something new about C# :) I think Juliet's method for a Parallel operation should be even faster than a simple loop.

**Benchmarks:**
Thanks to Mikael Svenson: http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2009/12/filling-array-with-default-value.html

It turns out the simple `for` loop is the way to go unless you want to use unsafe code.

Apologies for not being clearer in my original post. Eric and Mark are both correct in their comments; need to have more focused questions for sure. Thanks for everyone's suggestions and responses.

Comment: Note that for bytes, Mark's answer needs a slight modification.

byte[] image = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)255, [....]).ToArray();

Otherwise it will assume you want int[] returned.

Comment: If you have to go the performance route I suspect using unsafe/fixed and set either an Int32 or Int64 at a time and moving the pointer would be the quickest you can achieve in c# (and using a byte for the left over bytes).

Comment: Good points about testing the performance. Will definitely do that :)

Comment: I see questions like this all the time on SO: "I want to do x. There's a language construct y which was specifically designed to do x. I don't want to use it."  Why not? Why do you not want to use a loop?  Loops were designed to solve exactly this sort of problem, so why wouldn't you use one?

Comment: Eric, while I can understand the pain you must feel sometimes, there *might* be perf reasons here. And depending on his use case they might even be justified...

Comment: Sure, there might be. My point is that without knowing *why* the user is rejecting the obvious solution it is hard to recommend alternatives.

Comment: Eric - it was just a curiosity if there was a framework method similar to memset I didn't know about. A loop does work just fine, although I might try to benchmark Juliet's parallel option.

Comment: Did some benchmarking for fun at http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2009/12/filling-array-with-default-value.html

Comment: @MikaelSvenson you could add a test for konrad.kruczynski's method. It's for what I see, the best one here. And I totally disagree with Eric, that loops should be used, because they are good enough. With such an attitude no one would ever create such libraries like, say Dynamitey to make "better" reflection.

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer Code and benchmarks are updated to include PInvoke and memset delegate.

Answer (score 61):

You could use [**`Enumerable.Repeat`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
byte[] a = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)10, 100).ToArray();
```

The first parameter is the element you want repeated, and the second parameter is the number of times to repeat it.

This is OK for small arrays but you should use the looping method if you are dealing with very large arrays and performance is a concern.

Comment: Note that this is going to be tens of times slower than simply writing a loop. The array in question is millions of items long; the performance concern is likely quite germane.

Comment: The perfomance of this code must be pretty awful, even for not so large arrays (compared to a for-loop). The ToArray extension method does not know the length of the enumeration before it enumerates it. So it's forced to reallocate the array and copy the elements many times before it's done.

Comment: Totally agree Mark and thanks for the comments. I should have been clearer from the start for my reasons behind the question.

Comment: This is in no way like memset. It returns a new byte array rather than changing the contents of an existing byte array, which is a huge difference in many applications of memset.

Answer (score 55):

Actually, there is little known IL operation called [Initblk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initblk(v=vs.110).aspx) ([English version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initblk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) which does exactly that. So, let's use it as a method that doesn't require "unsafe". Here's the helper class:

```
public static class Util
{
    static Util()
    {
        var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("Memset", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, CallingConventions.Standard,
            null, new [] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(byte), typeof(int) }, typeof(Util), true);

        var generator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Initblk);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MemsetDelegate = (Action<IntPtr, byte, int>)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IntPtr, byte, int>));
    }

    public static void Memset(byte[] array, byte what, int length)
    {
        var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        MemsetDelegate(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), what, length);
        gcHandle.Free();
    }

    public static void ForMemset(byte[] array, byte what, int length)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = what;
        }
    }

    private static Action<IntPtr, byte, int> MemsetDelegate;

}
```

And what is the performance? Here's my result for Windows/.NET and Linux/Mono (different PCs).

```
Mono/for:     00:00:01.1356610
Mono/initblk: 00:00:00.2385835 

.NET/for:     00:00:01.7463579
.NET/initblk: 00:00:00.5953503
```

So it's worth considering. Note that the resulting IL will not be verifiable.

Comment: I observed a much larger difference. To initialize an 10MB array 1000 times, it takes 0.5s with initblk, and 22s with a loop. Here's my benchmark: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/6f653d8b3a82b1d038e1

Comment: That's even more interesting :) With your benchmark my results are: 3.66s vs 0.3s.

Comment: Looks like `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.InitBlock` now does the same thing.

Comment: Indeed, as can be seen here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il#L208 @Gman consider sharing this information as an answer.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski thank you for the idea! I've already added the answer with example code, and created the edit to include the source code link.

Comment: But frankly, IMO, it'll reach more people, if you edit your answer. Such is the SO system :)

Answer (score 24):

Building on [Lucero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518800/177710), here is a faster version. It will double the number of bytes copied using `Buffer.BlockCopy` every iteration. Interestingly enough, it outperforms it by a factor of 10 when using relatively small arrays (1000), but the difference is not that large for larger arrays (1000000), it is always faster though. The good thing about it is that it performs well even down to small arrays. It becomes faster than the naive approach at around length = 100. For a one million element byte array, it was 43 times faster.
(tested on Intel i7, .Net 2.0)

```
public static void MemSet(byte[] array, byte value) {
    if (array == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    int block = 32, index = 0;
    int length = Math.Min(block, array.Length);

    //Fill the initial array
    while (index < length) {
        array[index++] = value;
    }

    length = array.Length;
    while (index < length) {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, index, Math.Min(block, length-index));
        index += block;
        block *= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

A little bit late, but the following approach might be a good compromise without reverting to unsafe code. Basically it initializes the beginning of the array using a conventional loop and then reverts to `Buffer.BlockCopy()`, which should be as fast as you can get using a managed call.

```
public static void MemSet(byte[] array, byte value) {
  if (array == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
  }
  const int blockSize = 4096; // bigger may be better to a certain extent
  int index = 0;
  int length = Math.Min(blockSize, array.Length);
  while (index < length) {
    array[index++] = value;
  }
  length = array.Length;
  while (index < length) {
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, index, Math.Min(blockSize, length-index));
    index += blockSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: @downvoter What's wrong with my answer? Any suggestion for improvement?

Comment: Also worth noting that input parameters of Buffer.BlockCopy (indexes and lengths) are byte-array indexes and lengths, so for replicating this into lets say array of integers you need to multiply Buffer.BlockCopy indexes and lengths it by sizeof(int).

Answer (score 19):

Looks like `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.InitBlock` now does the same thing as the `OpCodes.Initblk` instruction that Konrad's answer mentions (he also mentioned a [source link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il#L208)).

The code to fill in the array is as follows:

```
byte[] a = new byte[N];
byte valueToFill = 255;

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.InitBlock(ref a[0], valueToFill, (uint) a.Length);
```

Comment: Cool, but it looks this is only in .NET core

Comment: it is possible to do this with a valueToFill incrementable like valueToFill++ ? for each case? 1.2.3.4.5....

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.initblock) says `The startAddress pointer is assumed to be pointer-aligned.`. How do we achieve that?

Answer (score 14):

This simple implementation uses successive doubling, and performs quite well (about 3-4 times faster than the naive version according to my benchmarks):

```
public static void Memset<T>(T[] array, T elem) 
{
    int length = array.Length;
    if (length == 0) return;
    array[0] = elem;
    int count;
    for (count = 1; count <= length/2; count*=2)
        Array.Copy(array, 0, array, count, count);
    Array.Copy(array, 0, array, count, length - count);
}
```

Edit: upon reading the other answers, it seems I'm not the only one with this idea. Still, I'm leaving this here, since it's a bit cleaner and it performs on par with the others.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about using Array.Copy this way.  http://coding.grax.com/2011/11/initialize-array-to-value-in-c-very.html

Comment: Grax32's link does not work anymore, but I think the new address is this one: https://grax32.com/2014/04/better-array-fill-function.html

Answer (score 13):

With the advent of [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1) (which is dotnet core only, but [it is the future of dotnet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-1/)) you have yet another way of solving this problem:

```
var array = new byte[100];
var span = new Span<byte>(array);

span.Fill(255);
```

Comment: This is by far the fastest way, regardless of array size. At least twice as fast as Array.Copy and Buffer.BlockCopy, and magnitudes faster than everything else. Span FTW!

Answer (score 12):

[Or use P/Invoke way](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt/memset.html):

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", 
EntryPoint = "memset", 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int count);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[3];
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    MemSet(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 0x7, arr.Length); 
}
```

Comment: Kind remainder: Do not forget unpinning GC pinned variables, such memory would not be automatically released.

Answer (score 11):

If performance is critical, you could consider using unsafe code and working directly with a pointer to the array.

Another option could be importing memset from msvcrt.dll and use that. However, the overhead from invoking that might easily be larger than the gain in speed.

Comment: Yeah, it is about 40 times faster than Repeat<> or a for-loop.

Comment: Importing memset? Interesting..will have to give that a shot.

Comment: @jedidja

You can find a code example here: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=389926

Comment: Yeah, it's going to depend a lot on the size of the array.  I once solved a large performance problem by substantially reducing the number of interop calls.

Answer (score 6):

If performance is absolutely critical, then `Enumerable.Repeat(n, m).ToArray()` will be too slow for your needs. You might be able to crank out faster performance using PLINQ or [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28VS.100%29.aspx):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

byte initialValue = 20;
byte[] data = new byte[size]
Parallel.For(0, size, index => data[index] = initialValue);
```

Comment: Yes - great observation and actually we are using Parallel.For elsewhere for image processing code.

Comment: Yeah, but don't you feel dirty parallelizing initialization code?!? ;)

Comment: This code is incorrect as presented.  The second parameter of Parallel.For is toExclusive, meaning the last byte of the array is unaltered.  Change `size - 1` to `size`.

Comment: how big `size` should be to make sense to parallel this initialization code?

Comment: This would most likely be slower than a trivial for loop

Comment: Just as Kip9000 points out, this will be slower than the simple ```for``` loop. Check out the performance comparison [mentioned in the OP](http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2009/12/filling-array-with-default-value.html).

Answer (score 5):

All answers are writing single bytes only - what if you want to fill a byte array with words? Or floats? I find use for that now and then. So after having written similar code to 'memset' in a non-generic way a few times and arriving at this page to find good code for single bytes, I went about writing the method below.

I think PInvoke and C++/CLI each have their drawbacks. And why not have the runtime 'PInvoke' for you into mscorxxx? Array.Copy and Buffer.BlockCopy are native code certainly. BlockCopy isn't even 'safe' - you can copy a long halfway over another, or over a DateTime as long as they're in arrays.

At least I wouldn't go file new C++ project for things like this - it's a waste of time almost certainly.

So here's basically an extended version of the solutions presented by Lucero and TowerOfBricks that can be used to memset longs, ints, etc as well as single bytes.

```
public static class MemsetExtensions
{
    static void MemsetPrivate(this byte[] buffer, byte[] value, int offset, int length) {
        var shift = 0;
        for (; shift < 32; shift++)
            if (value.Length == 1 << shift)
                break;
        if (shift == 32 || value.Length != 1 << shift)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "The source array must have a length that is a power of two and be shorter than 4GB.", "value");

        int remainder;
        int count = Math.DivRem(length, value.Length, out remainder);

        var si = 0;
        var di = offset;
        int cx;
        if (count < 1) 
            cx = remainder;
        else 
            cx = value.Length;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(value, si, buffer, di, cx);
        if (cx == remainder)
            return;

        var cachetrash = Math.Max(12, shift); // 1 << 12 == 4096
        si = di;
        di += cx;
        var dx = offset + length;
        // doubling up to 1 << cachetrash bytes i.e. 2^12 or value.Length whichever is larger
        for (var al = shift; al <= cachetrash && di + (cx = 1 << al) < dx; al++) {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, si, buffer, di, cx);
            di += cx;
        }
        // cx bytes as long as it fits
        for (; di + cx <= dx; di += cx)
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, si, buffer, di, cx);
        // tail part if less than cx bytes
        if (di < dx)
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, si, buffer, di, dx - di);
    }
}
```

Having this you can simply add short methods to take the value type you need to memset with and call the private method, e.g. just find replace ulong in this method:

```
    public static void Memset(this byte[] buffer, ulong value, int offset, int count) {
        var sourceArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        MemsetPrivate(buffer, sourceArray, offset, sizeof(ulong) * count);
    }
```

Or go silly and do it with any type of struct (although the MemsetPrivate above only works for structs that marshal to a size that is a power of two):

```
    public static void Memset<T>(this byte[] buffer, T value, int offset, int count) where T : struct {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        var sourceArray = new byte[size];
        try {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(value, ptr, false);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, sourceArray, 0, size);
        } finally {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
        MemsetPrivate(buffer, sourceArray, offset, count * size);
    }
```

I changed the initblk mentioned before to take ulongs to compare performance with my code and that silently fails - the code runs but the resulting buffer contains the least significant byte of the ulong only.

Nevertheless I compared the performance writing as big a buffer with for, initblk and my memset method. The times are in ms total over 100 repetitions writing 8 byte ulongs whatever how many times fit the buffer length. The for version is manually loop-unrolled for the 8 bytes of a single ulong.

```
Buffer Len  #repeat  For millisec  Initblk millisec   Memset millisec
0x00000008  100      For   0,0032  Initblk   0,0107   Memset   0,0052
0x00000010  100      For   0,0037  Initblk   0,0102   Memset   0,0039
0x00000020  100      For   0,0032  Initblk   0,0106   Memset   0,0050
0x00000040  100      For   0,0053  Initblk   0,0121   Memset   0,0106
0x00000080  100      For   0,0097  Initblk   0,0121   Memset   0,0091
0x00000100  100      For   0,0179  Initblk   0,0122   Memset   0,0102
0x00000200  100      For   0,0384  Initblk   0,0123   Memset   0,0126
0x00000400  100      For   0,0789  Initblk   0,0130   Memset   0,0189
0x00000800  100      For   0,1357  Initblk   0,0153   Memset   0,0170
0x00001000  100      For   0,2811  Initblk   0,0167   Memset   0,0221
0x00002000  100      For   0,5519  Initblk   0,0278   Memset   0,0274
0x00004000  100      For   1,1100  Initblk   0,0329   Memset   0,0383
0x00008000  100      For   2,2332  Initblk   0,0827   Memset   0,0864
0x00010000  100      For   4,4407  Initblk   0,1551   Memset   0,1602
0x00020000  100      For   9,1331  Initblk   0,2768   Memset   0,3044
0x00040000  100      For  18,2497  Initblk   0,5500   Memset   0,5901
0x00080000  100      For  35,8650  Initblk   1,1236   Memset   1,5762
0x00100000  100      For  71,6806  Initblk   2,2836   Memset   3,2323
0x00200000  100      For  77,8086  Initblk   2,1991   Memset   3,0144
0x00400000  100      For 131,2923  Initblk   4,7837   Memset   6,8505
0x00800000  100      For 263,2917  Initblk  16,1354   Memset  33,3719
```

I excluded the first call every time, since both initblk and memset take a hit of I believe it was about .22ms for the first call. Slightly surprising my code is faster for filling short buffers than initblk, seeing it got half a page full of setup code.

If anybody feels like optimizing this, go ahead really. It's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Tested several ways, described in different answers.
See sources of test in c# [test class](https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/blob/master/csharp-tips/csharp-tips/csharp-tips/FillArrayTests.cs)

[image: benchmark report]

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core has a built-in Array.Fill() function, but sadly .NET Framework is missing it. .NET Core has two variations: fill the entire array and fill a portion of the array starting at an index.

Building on the ideas above, here is a more generic Fill function that will fill the entire array of several data types. This is the fastest function when benchmarking against other methods discussed in this post.

This function, along with the version that fills a portion an array are available in an open source and free NuGet package ([HPCsharp on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HPCsharp/)). Also included is a slightly faster version of Fill using SIMD/SSE instructions that performs only memory writes, whereas BlockCopy-based methods perform memory reads and writes.

```
    public static void FillUsingBlockCopy<T>(this T[] array, T value) where T : struct
    {
        int numBytesInItem = 0;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte) || typeof(T) == typeof(sbyte))
            numBytesInItem = 1;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ushort) || typeof(T) != typeof(short))
            numBytesInItem = 2;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(uint) || typeof(T) != typeof(int))
            numBytesInItem = 4;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ulong) || typeof(T) != typeof(long))
            numBytesInItem = 8;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type '{0}' is unsupported.", typeof(T).ToString()));

        int block = 32, index = 0;
        int endIndex = Math.Min(block, array.Length);

        while (index < endIndex)          // Fill the initial block
            array[index++] = value;

        endIndex = array.Length;
        for (; index < endIndex; index += block, block *= 2)
        {
            int actualBlockSize = Math.Min(block, endIndex - index);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, index * numBytesInItem, actualBlockSize * numBytesInItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it when you initialize the array but I don't think that's what you are asking for:

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[5] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

Comment: That would be correct :) I'm working with images so the byte[] is several hundred thousand/million items large.

Answer (score 0):

Most of answers is for byte memset but if you want to use it for float or any other struct you should multiply index by size of your data. Because Buffer.BlockCopy will copy based on the bytes.
This code will be work for float values

```
public static void MemSet(float[] array, float value) {
    if (array == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    int block = 32, index = 0;
    int length = Math.Min(block, array.Length);

    //Fill the initial array
    while (index < length) {
        array[index++] = value;
    }

    length = array.Length;
    while (index < length) {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, index * sizeof(float), Math.Min(block, length-index)* sizeof(float));
        index += block;
        block *= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Array object has a method called Clear. I'm willing to bet that the Clear method is faster than any code you can write in C#.

Comment: Fill with a _non-zero_ value. See the documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

you can try the following codes, it will work.

```
byte[]   test =   new   byte[65536]; 
Array.Clear(test,0,test.Length);
```

Comment: The question states filling with a _non-zero_ value.