# C# Array.Value differs from created array in c++

Tags: c#, integer

What is the best way to handle the following situation in C#?

I have a server application written in C/C++.

For example
It creates a `unsigned char` buffer with length `256`.
In this buffer the server stores the data the client sends to it. After storing, there are some cryptography checks with the received buffer.

I'm writing a client for this server in C#.

The problem is the buffer the server is expecting at fixed length of 256.

When I create a `byte[]` array with content and total length of 256 the cryptography checks are failing.

The reason I found out is simple. The server expects a buffer of 256 bytes long. For example if the message is `"Hello World"`, the rest of the buffer has to be 0-padded.
Or, better explained: the bytes need to be `(unsigned) "204"` or  `(signed) "-52"`.

I think this is a C/C++ concept issue/problem.

To solve my problem, I am setting that value explicitly.

```
public static byte[] GetCBuffer(this byte[] data, int len)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(i < data.Length)
            tmp[i] = data[i];
        else
            tmp[i] = 204;
    return tmp;
}
```

Are there better ways to work with these art expected bytes? Am I not seeing something essential?

Comment: Based on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150310/2145211) to _Initialize a byte array to a certain value, other than the default null?_ I would say your solution is a good one.

Comment: I would generalize further and pass in the "blank" value, so you could reuse again without modification if the value is something other than 204.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like `if` in your code, you can try LINQ:

```
public static byte[] GetCBuffer(this byte[] data, int len)
{
    byte[] tmp = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)204, len).ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
      tmp[i] = data[i];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

But conceptually, it's the same, just looks (arguably) a bit nicer.

Comment: You might also replace the loop with a Zip and put the ToArray on the return.

Answer (score 1):

Can you 'memset' the entire array to the desired fill character and then insert the actual data?

Comment: That sounds like a more readable result, plus you can `Buffer.BlockCopy` the data after clearing it.

Comment: Can you specify your idea? How to implement memset without pinvoke overhead? In fact, i already trye'd BlockCopy before. But the elements than are 0 filled. Whitch will fail at the server side when the elements are treated.

Comment: Your post stated this: "I have a server application written in C/C++.
... it creates a unsigned char buffer with length 256."  So I assumed it was C/C++ and it needed to be done when the array was created.