# How to write these commands to Serial Port?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

[image]

In the above table there is a command "CLR" with Description(hex)  "OC"

When I write that command to serial port  I write  "`port.Write(new byte[]{ 0x0C } )` " 
and that works.

But I don't really understand how to write other commands in this list to serial port
for example `ESC DC1` command , `ESC Q A...........CR` command

Can someone please give me a bit of a explanation about these Code descriptions ? 
and how should I format them when I write to serial port ?

Please help me, I appreciate your help very much. :)  Please be so kind enough to help me.

Comment: Please give me a clue at least

Comment: Google............ :)

Comment: But I don't understand what keyword to google for

Comment: Can you please help me ? , or please tell me a keyword which I should google for ?

Comment: Please give me a clue... :(

Comment: One pleading comment is sufficient.

Comment: As  your doc says `ESC=0x1B` and `DC1=0x11`, So similar to your port.Write

Comment: Do just what you did for CLR, but include the additional values, separated by commas. See the answer to this question to see how to initialize a byte array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150097/initialize-a-byte-array-to-a-certain-value-other-than-the-default-null

Comment: Google "ascii table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just doing the same thing for the other commands as you did for the CLR command? E.g. for ESC DC1:

> port.Write(new byte[]{ 0x1B, 0x11 } );

Or for your other command:

> port.Write(new byte[]{ 0x1B, 0x51, 0x41 } );
>
> //Then write the 20 bytes that you want in your line,and then...
>
> port.Write(new byte[]{ 0xD } );

Comment: Oh , I was not sure how to write it when there are two pieaces in same command like "1B 11"

Comment: Osvetsky,  One more thing, Please tell me how to write this one "B 51 44 [n ]x20 0D " ?

Comment: and what is that "[n ]x20 OD" in "B 51 44 [n ]x20 0D"   ? 
if write "0XB , 0X51 , 0X44" then we are only writing "B 51 44" this, right ?

Comment: You write 3 bytes (0x1B, 0x51, 0x41), then you write 20 more bytes that represent the line you want to display, then you write 1 more byte (0xD), so in total you write 24 bytes.