# Perform a Telnet handshake

Tags: c#, telnet, handshake

I am writing a (hopefully simple) console app to send commands to an audio device running telnet. These commands allow me to alter the state of DSP components contained within it, for example: `ToneGen set mute true`.

Where I am having trouble is the telnet handshake, I understand that there are a number of commands sent from the Telnet Server to the client and that the client needs to respond to these in order to successfully negotiate the start of the session. I just don't know to send the correct commands. Below is my some what unsuccessful attempt.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace telnetTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.101");
            int port = 23;
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine("Establishing Connection to {0}", address);

            s.Connect(endpoint);


            byte[] Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0xFC\0xFC\0XFC");
            s.Send(Bytes);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
            s.Receive(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the code is as follows:

```
Establishing Connection to 192.168.10.101
??↑?? ??#??'??$
```

So I think I have two core issues here:

1) How to detect the handshake request from the audio device
2) How to send the appropriate response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int vari = s.Receive(buffer);
string hex1 = vari.ToString("X");
Console.WriteLine(hex1);
```

After connecting hex1 returns a value of 15

**UPDATE 2**

```
Console.WriteLine("Sending Bytes");
byte[] Bytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0xFF 0xFC 0x18 0xFF 0xFD 0x20 0xFF 0xFC 0x23 0xFF 0xFD 0x27 0xFF 0xFC 0x24 \n");
s.Send(Bytes1);
```

After the above code I am looking for the next response from the server by using the the following code,

```
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
int byteCount2 = s.Receive(buffer2);
Console.WriteLine(byteCount2 + " Bytes Found");
```

All I am seeing in the console is the Phrase "Sending Bytes" so it appears that `Bytes1` is not being sent and there are no further response bytes to read.

Comment: Hint: take a debugger and check `Bytes` array contains the bytes you're expecting. Hint #2: always take a debugger and check that every variable has the expected value at every point in time while your program executes.

Comment: @zerkms - So I attached a debugger and discovered the value noted in update 1 in the original post, _if_ the response F stored in `hex1` (hex/int 15) is equal to 0xFF then it appears that I am on the right track when considering the example negotiation procedure in the following  [link](https://support.biamp.com/Tesira/Control/Telnet_session_negotiation_in_Tesira). I am not sure if this is actually correct though or if my logic is flawed?

Comment: I believe `s.Receive` returns you the *length* of the received request. So `15` is how many bytes were received.

Comment: @zerkms so I have now had a measure of success returning the `Bytes` and have received the following hex: `FF FD 18 FF FD 20 FF FD 23 FF FD 27 FF FD 24` now I need to respond with a similar request being `0xFF 0xFC 0x18 0xFF 0xFD 0x20 0xFF 0xFC 0x23 0xFF 0xFD 0x27 0xFF 0xFC 0x24` what I am not sure about here is the delimiter between hex values, as you can see I used a space in the above, I'll post the new code as update 2 now.

Comment: Now you need to check my initial suggestion once again: `"0xFF 0xFC 0x18 0xFF 0xFD 0x20 0xFF 0xFC 0x23 0xFF 0xFD 0x27 0xFF 0xFC 0x24 \n"` it's not how you create an array of bytes. Just check the `Bytes1` and see that it is rubbish. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150310/251311 - this would be another hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I think I have two core issues here:
>
> 1) How to detect the handshake request from the audio device
>   2) How to send the appropriate response.

**1) How to detect the handshake request from the audio device**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int byteCount = s.Receive(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(byteCount + " Bytes Found");
DumpBytes(buffer, byteCount);
```

`DumpBytes(buffer, byteCount);` function found on MSDN: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) 
displays the contents of `buffer` in the console window, this is useful for checking the response from the telnet server once connected.

**2) How to send the appropriate response (back to the telnet server).**

```
var handshake1 = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x18, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x20, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x23, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x27, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x24 };
s.Send(handshake1);
```