# Null Reference Exception when calling an Object Array

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I tried to get some help earlier and I don't think I provided enough information though I appreciate all the advice.

The goal is simply to add a new instance of the Object Room to an array and print to a list box.  When a user attempts to enter a room name that is already in existence it should simply display in the specs for the room that is already in the array.

I keep getting a null reference exception.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Room_Class
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Room[] roomArray = new Room[20];
        int count = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddRm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double length, width, height;
            if (VerifyRoomName() == true)
            {


                if (txtRmLen.Text == "" || txtRmWid.Text == "" || txtRmHt.Text == "")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < roomArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (txtRmName.Text == roomArray[i].getRoomName())
                        {
                            txtRmName.Text = roomArray[i].getRoomName();
                            txtRmLen.Text = roomArray[i].getLength().ToString();
                            txtRmHt.Text = roomArray[i].getCeilingHeight().ToString();
                            txtRmWid.Text = roomArray[i].getWidth().ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            roomArray[count] = new Room(roomName);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        length = double.Parse(txtRmLen.Text);
                        width = double.Parse(txtRmWid.Text);
                        height = double.Parse(txtRmHt.Text);
                        for (int i = 0; i < roomArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (txtRmName.Text == roomArray[i].getRoomName())
                            {
                                txtRmName.Text = roomArray[i].getRoomName();
                                txtRmLen.Text = roomArray[i].getLength().ToString();
                                txtRmHt.Text = roomArray[i].getCeilingHeight().ToString();
                                txtRmWid.Text = roomArray[i].getWidth().ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                roomArray[count] = new Room(roomName, length, width, height);
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\nPlease Enter Valid Values", "Error!");
                    }
                }  
                PrintList();
            }

        }


        private void PrintList()
        {
            double paintTotal = 0, feetTotal = 0;
            string RoomName;
            lstRoomList.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                RoomName = roomArray[i].getRoomName() + "\t" + roomArray[i].SquareFeet().ToString("n1") + "\t" + roomArray[i].GallonsPaint().ToString("n1");
                lstRoomList.Items.Add(RoomName);
                paintTotal += roomArray[i].GallonsPaint();
                feetTotal += roomArray[i].SquareFeet();
                lblTtlGallons.Text = paintTotal.ToString("n1");
                lblTtlSqFt.Text = feetTotal.ToString("n1");
            }
        }

        private bool VerifyRoomName()
        {
            if (roomName == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Room Name", "Error!");
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the exception?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be

```
if (roomArray[i] != null)
```

Whenever you create an array, you'll have to initialize it's individual items before you can access them.

```
Room[] roomArray = new Room[20];

roomArray[0] = new Room();
```

Comment: was about to give same answer but then found out that OP is initializing `roomArray` in likes of this part `roomArray[count] = new Room(roomName);`  // though having it in else part is suspicious

Comment: @Bingo Yeah i saw that too... i just figure his biggest problem is probably understanding how to use arrays in general, hence my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Because the elements of Room inside Room[] we're not initialized.

Try

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for(int i = 0; i < roomyArray.Length; i++) roomArray[i] = new Room();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, you need to initialize the array before you start using it. When you write:

```
Room[] roomArray = new Room[20];
```

What you are telling the computer to do is reserve you enough memory for references to 20 objects of the type `Room`. The other solutions proposed are fine, but if you want performance, try the following:

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897555/what-is-the-equivalent-of-memset-in-c) SO answer, using the following function would be more performant than the other solutions provided thus far. This also has supporting evidence from [this blog post.](http://techmikael.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/filling-array-with-default-value.html)

*Note: I've converted to use generics*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills an array with a default value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">The array to fill with a default value</param>
    /// <param name="value">The default value</param>
    public static void MemSet<T>(T[] array, T value)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
        }

        int block = 32, index = 0;
        int length = Math.Min(block, array.Length);

        //Fill the initial array
        while (index < length)
        {
            array[index++] = value;
        }

        length = array.Length;
        while (index < length)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, index, Math.Min(block, length - index));
            index += block;
            block *= 2;
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
Memset<Room>(roomArray, new Room());
```