# Fill T[] with default value depending on type

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    public T[] gridArray;


    public Grid(int size)
    {
        gridArray = new T[size];

        gridArray.FillArray<T>();
    }

}
```

I'd like my `gridArray.FillArray<T>();` method to fill the `gridArray` with `-1`, if it's of type `int` and to fill it with `false`, if it's of type `bool`.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `default(T)` will give you `0` when `T` is `int`, and `false` when `T` is `bool`. There's no *good* way to get `-1` for `int` in a generic fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two concerns in this question

### How to create an array with non-default prefilled values?

There is no clean way to fill a generic array with custom default value, except for creating it manually.

You might want to read this StackOverflow question too, because it is related to this topic:
[What is the equivalent of memset in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897555/what-is-the-equivalent-of-memset-in-c)

Taking this into account, you can define your `Grid` class as the following:

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    private T[] _gridArray;  

    public Grid(int size)
    {
        _gridArray = new T[size];
    }            

    public Grid(int size, T initialValue)
    {
        _gridArray = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            _gridArray[i] = initialValue;

        // or it can be rewritten with LINQ, if you like:
        // _gridArray = Enumerable.Repeat(initialValue, size).ToArray();
    }    
}
```

Now, you can use it to create default arrays:

```
var grid = new Grid<int>(3); // [0, 0, 0]
var grid = new Grid<object>(3); // [null, null, null]
var grid = new Grid<bool>(4); // [false, false, false, false]
```

but you can also provide a value which you would like to be as a default:

```
var grid = new Grid<int>(3, -1); // [-1, -1, -1]
var grid = new Grid<bool>(4, true); // [true, true, true, true]
```

### How to set custom default values per generic T

If you want `-1` to be default value for **all** `Grid<int>`, you can create a factory, which will know about it and create this according to this logic. This factory can store default values for each type and validate your `T` against them.

Of course, you could put this logic into constructor just like you initially wanted it to be:

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _customDefaultValues = new Dictionary<Type, object>
    {
        [typeof(int)] = -1,
        [typeof(long)] = long.MaxValue
    };

    public T[] _gridArray;  

    public Grid(int size)
    {
        _gridArray = new T[size];

        if (_customDefaultValues.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object defaultValue))
        {
            T defaultValueUnboxed = (T)defaultValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                _gridArray[i] = defaultValueUnboxed;
        }
    }  
}

var grid = new Grid<int>(4); // [-1, -1, -1, -1]
var grid = new Grid<long>(2); // [long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue]
var grid = new Grid<bool>(3); // [false, false, false]
```

but for me it looks a little bit sloppy and non-transparent. Also, it creates new instance of static `_customDefaultValues` for each create closed generic type. That's why it would be better to extract it to a factory class.

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    private T[] _gridArray;  

    public Grid(int size)
    {
        _gridArray = new T[size];
    }            

    public Grid(int size, T initialValue)
    {
        _gridArray = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            _gridArray[i] = initialValue;
    }    
}

public static class GridFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _customDefaultValues = new Dictionary<Type, object>
    {
        [typeof(int)] = -1,
        [typeof(long)] = long.MaxValue
    };

    public static Grid<T> Create<T>(int size)
    {
        if (_customDefaultValues.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object defaultValue))
            return new Grid<T>(size, (T)defaultValue);

        return new Grid<T>(size);
    }        
}
```

It results into more code, but this way it looks more clear:

```
var grid = GridFactory.Create<int>(3); // [-1, -1, -1]
var grid = GridFactory.Create<long>(4); // [long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue]
var grid = GridFactory.Create<object>(3); // [null, null, null] by default
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to create an extension method for this. One option is to use overloading and implement separate method for every type you need

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void FillArray(this int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    public static void FillArray(this bool[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible to use this approach when you explicitely create `int` or `bool` array

```
var arr = new int[size];
arr.FillArray();
```

And it is not possible to use this approach with generic parameter like you do in `Grid`. So another option would be creating generic extension method with checking type in runtime

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void FillArray<T>(this T[] array)
    {
        Type itemType = typeof(T);

        T value;
        if (itemType == typeof(bool))
        {
            value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(false, itemType);
        }
        else if (itemType == typeof(int))
        {
            value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(-1, itemType);
        }
        else
        {
            value = default(T);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

Consider the fact that when you instantiate an array (`new type[size]`) it is already filled by default value of its type (`0` for `int` and `false` for `bool`). So possibly you won't need these extension method if default values are okay for you.