# Create managed .NET array without initializing to all zeros

Tags: .net, arrays

Take the following C# method:

```
static double[] AddArrays(double[] left, double[] right)
{
    if (left.Length != right.Length) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Arrays to add are not the same length");
    }

    double[] result = new double[left.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; i++) {
        result[i] = left[i] + right[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

As I understand it, the CLR will initialize `result` to all zeros, even though `AddArrays` is just about to completely initialize it anyway. Is there any way to avoid this extra work? Even if it means using unsafe C#, C++/CLI, or raw IL code?

EDIT: Can't be done, for the reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648814/direct-array-initialization-with-a-constant-value/648818#648818).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648814/direct-array-initialization-with-a-constant-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
static IEnumerable<double> Add(IEnumerable<double> left, IEnumerable<double> right)
{ 
    using (IEnumerator<double> l = left.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<double> r = right.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (l.MoveNext() && r.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return l.Current + r.Current;
        }

        if (l.MoveNext() || r.MoveNext())
            throw new ArgumentException("Sequences to add are not the same length");
    }
}
```

You can pass your double arrays to this function.  If you really need an array as the result (hint: you probably don't) you can just call `.ToArray()` on the function's return value.

.Net 4 will have a function already built in for this:

```
 double[] array1 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
 double[] array2 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
 IEnumerable<double> result = array1.Zip(array2, (a,b) => a + b);

 foreach(double d in result)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(d);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need the result in array form eventually, though this gives me an idea for seeing how long lazy-evaluation could work in my situation (e.g., to combine two operators into one realized operation).