# Weird Inline Array Initialization

Tags: c#, arrays

I found this code snippet on a different post that I don't quite understand and would appriciate someone explaining.

```
private bool[] GetPageNumbersToLink(IPagedResult result)
{
   if (result.TotalPages <= 9)
      return new bool[result.TotalPages + 1].Select(b => true).ToArray();

   ...
```

[C# Array initialization - with non-default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136836/c-array-initialization-with-non-default-value)

My take on this:

```
new bool[result.TotalPages + 1]
```

this creates an array of bools with length equal to that of the totalpages, the default value being false on all of them.

```
.Select(b => true)
```

this uses a linq query to return only the items that are true, i.e. none of them

```
.ToArray();
```

linq returns IEnumerable or something, so it needs to go back to a new array, of length 0 as none were selected in the first place.

I think that's what it's doing, but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: One sometimes get confused by the word `Select` since it sounds like: **"filter"** the source (however that is called `Where`); in fact it means: **"project"** the source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(EDIT: Oops, misread the post (unless it was edited without me noticing).)

No, that's not what it's doing. The result is effectively:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(true, result.TotalPages + 1).ToArray();
```

The `Select` call doesn't depend on the value that it's selecting at all - it's just returning `true` whatever the input is. `Select` doesn't perform filtering, just projection.

In other words:

```
// Array filled with (result.TotalPages + 1) x false
new bool[result.TotalPages + 1]

// Sequence of length (result.TotalPages + 1) x true
.Select(b => true)

// Array filled with (result.TotalPages + 1) x true
.ToArray();
```

Anyway it's inefficient. It's occasionally unfortunate that .NET doesn't provide something like:

```
public static T[] CreateFilledArray<T>(T value, int size)
{
    T[] ret = new T[size];
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = value;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The first line of this answer is a bit misleading... it's not actually doing what the OP describes.  Select isn't performing any type of filter, it's returning true for each item in the array.

Comment: It looks like you meant to make that last method a generic one.

Answer (score 5):

> `.Select(b => true)`
>
> this uses a linq query to return only the items that are true, i.e. none of them

No, it means that for each item, it returns true. It doesn't do any test on the value of the array item

This code just creates an array with all items set to true

I prefer this form (no intermediate array) :

```
return new Enumerable.Range(0,result.TotalPages).Select(b => true).ToArray();
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat` is a more descriptive way of doing this, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the .Select(b => true) part returns "true" for every element in the array, so you actually get IEnumerable with result.TotalPages + 1 items and then it's converted to an array.