# Generic initialization of multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, which I want to initialize in a simple and fast way:

```
double[,,] arr = new double[4,5,6];
// doesn't work by design
foreach(double d in arr)
   d = ... ; // my initialization value
```

This obviously doesn't works. But I would like to have a generic function for setting all array values to a choosen default. With own classes, I could write a special constructor, but with value types I've no real idea. With C++, I could access all items in a linear way with one for loop, but in C# I think I've to use as much for loops as I have dimensions. I've no better solution at the moment ( or I'm using unsafe code and pointer arithmetics, which would probably work.).

Is there a more elegant way for doing this ?

Comment: If you're concerned with speed, don't use multidimensional arrays. They're very slow in .NET (compared to single dimensional arrays anyway). Even jagged arrays are faster, despite the pointer chasing. The simplest+fastest thing to do here is make it 1-dimensional and do the indexing math yourself.

Comment: this is somehow related and found it interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136836/c-sharp-array-initialization-with-non-default-value

Comment: Thanks for your comments, speed is actual not an issue in my current application but I'd prefer a clean syntax here.

Comment: What do you mean by own classes vs. value types? You can write your own constructor for a `struct`, which is a value type, too. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: well, yes, but I meant basic types like double, int etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure if it's what you want, but the following extension method will allow you to initialise every value in an array, regardless of the number of dimensions.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this Array array, T defaultValue)
        {
            int[] indicies = new int[array.Rank];

            SetDimension<T>(array, indicies, 0, defaultValue);
        }

        private static void SetDimension<T>(Array array, int[] indicies, int dimension, T defaultValue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(dimension); i++)
            {
                indicies[dimension] = i;

                if (dimension < array.Rank - 1)
                    SetDimension<T>(array, indicies, dimension + 1, defaultValue);
                else
                    array.SetValue(defaultValue, indicies);
            }
        }
    }
```

Use like so:

```
int[, ,] test1 = new int[3, 4, 5];
test1.Set(1);

int[,] test2 = new int[3, 4];
test2.Set(1);

int[] test3 = new int[3];
test3.Set(1);
```

Comment: thank's, yes, exactly, that was my idea. It looks rather complicated, but it seems there is no really .net builtin solution for that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using a 1D array, and map the values sequentially. You will need to convert from indeces `i`, `j`, `k`, `...`  into the proper array index, which is done with the `Que()` function below, part of a generic array class `SeqArray<T>`.

```
// Test code first
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* 3 pages, of a 4x2 matrix
         * 
         *         |16 17|
         *      | 8  9|19|
         *   | 0  1|11|21|
         *   | 2  3|13|23|
         *   | 4  5|15|
         *   | 6  7|
         *   
         *  shown above are the sequential indeces for a rank 3 array
         */
        SeqArray<double> arr = new SeqArray<double>(3, 4, 2);
        // Initialize values to squential index "num"
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    arr[i, j, k] = num++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Check that the array values correspond to the index sequence
        num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 4 * 2; i++)
        {
            Trace.Assert(arr.InnerArray[i] == num++);
        }

        // Initialize with value=π
        arr = new SeqArray<double>(Math.PI, 4, 5, 6);
    }

}

public class SeqArray<T>
{
    T[] values;
    int[] lengths;

    public SeqArray(params int[] lengths)
    {
        this.lengths = lengths;
        int N = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
        {
            N *= lengths[i];
        }
        values = new T[N];
    }
    public SeqArray(T value, params int[] lengths) : this(lengths)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = value;
        }            
    }
    public int[] Lengths { get { return lengths; } }
    public int Size { get { return values.Length; } }
    internal T[] InnerArray { get { return values; } }
    public int Que(params int[] indeces)
    {
        // Check if indeces are omited like arr[4] instead of arr[4,0,0]
        if (indeces.Length < lengths.Length)
        {
            // Make a new index array padded with zeros
            int[] temp = new int[lengths.Length];
            indeces.CopyTo(temp, 0);
            indeces = temp;
        }
        // Count the elements for indeces
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < indeces.Length; i++)
        {
            k = lengths[i] * k + indeces[i];
        }
        return k;
    }

    public T this[params int[] indeces]
    {
        get { return values[Que(indeces)]; }
        set { values[Que(indeces)] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to create child classes for different numeric types in order to use the `+`, `-` operator overloading. To code a matrix multiplication would be a little work, but doable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-recursive version alternative to that posted by Andy Holt above:

```
    public static void SetAll<T>(this Array array, T value)
    {
        var sizes = new int[array.Rank];

        sizes[array.Rank - 1] = 1;
        for (var d = array.Rank - 2; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            sizes[d] = array.GetLength(d + 1)*sizes[d + 1];
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            var remainder = i;
            var index = new int[array.Rank];
            for (var d = 0; d < array.Rank && remainder > 0; d++)
            {
                index[d] = remainder / sizes[d];
                remainder -= index[d]*sizes[d];
            }
            array.SetValue(value, index);
        }
    }
```