# Filling an array of int at declaration

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to declare an array of int `rows` with a variable size (`X`) and init all values to 1. For the moment I use this :

```
int[] rows = new int[X];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
   rows[i] = 1;
}
```

Is there any faster/shorter way to do it with some sort of `fill(1)` or `int[] rows = new int[X] {1};` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ:

```
int[] rows = Enumerable.Repeat(element:1, count: X).ToArray();// named parameter -  X
                                                              // doesn't tell anything
```

Comment: As Eric Lippert notes, doing this is [tens of times slower than simply writing a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897555/what-is-the-equivalent-of-memset-in-c#comment1804854_1897564) (it [actually is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1051227/11683)).